# How to increase the processing speed of mysql query in pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

My ids in tuple is below

```
ids = tuple(df1['ids'])
```

the ids has 100k rows

My query

```
q_id=f'''

SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM NEWS 
WHERE status = 'JOINED' AND id IN {ids} 
GROUP BY 1
```

`connection` is a method which establish connection with username and password

```
df2 = connection('mysqldb', q_id)
```

It's taking too much time to get the result. How to increase the processing speed of mysql query in pandas?

Comment: How many rows you have in your db ? You can chunk read and process the query

Comment: if you run the same query in your server mysql ..is the same time ??

Comment: first I have got the ids from dataframe which is csv,after that I need to run the `q_id`

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar first I have got the ids from dataframe which is csv,after that I need to run the q_id

Comment: I know ...I just trying to say that maybe the problem is how are make the query

Comment: @YOandBEN_W, ids around near to 1 lakh rows. Since I am fetching from MySQL how to do chunk size for that, if we are doing something like read_csv(chunksize) can be given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE news`.

It needs to include

```
 INDEX(status, id)
```

Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If so, then this is a rather weird query to write:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS Count 
    FROM NEWS 
    WHERE status = 'JOINED'
      AND id IN {ids} 
    GROUP BY 1
```

because all the counts will be "1".  (This is because the `PRIMARY KEY` is "unique").

To find out *how many* of those ids are `'JOINED`':

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count 
    FROM NEWS 
    WHERE status = 'JOINED'
      AND id IN {ids}
```

To find out *which* of the ids are `'JOINED`':

```
SELECT id 
    FROM NEWS 
    WHERE status = 'JOINED'
      AND id IN {ids}
```

Answer (score 1):

For speed, it is almost always more efficient to combine queries.

Your Question implies that there are three steps (3 separate SQL queries) involved:

1. get a list of ids,
2. check the ids (the shown query finds which ids are 'joined'),
3. use those ids in some way.

Better would be to combine the queries together.  A simple way is to have the search for ids be a 'derived' table that provides the ids to the rest of the process.  Often it is better to blend the queries together even further.

(If we knew the rest of the processing, we might be able to provide a specific suggestion.)

Your query generates `0` or `1` for each id.  What if you got `NULL` or `id`?  Or find the `ids` that are "joined" and toss the rest?  Your query can be sped up by doing this.  However, it delivers that ids that are joined, not 0 or 1:

```
SELECT id FROM NEWS WHERE status = 'JOINED' AND id IN(...);
```

And this would help make it more efficient:

```
INDEX(status, id)
```

In the two examples below, I have focused on merging the 2nd and 3rd queries.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id FROM NEWS WHERE status = 'JOINED' ) x
            USING(id);
```

With that, you can either use the `id` or get a `NULL` indicating that it is not "joined".

That can also be written

```
SELECT ...
    FROM mytable AS a
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM NEWS
            WHERE status = 'JOINED'
              AND id = a.id )
```

That does actually yield `0` or `1`, being treated as `false` or `true`.

It is unclear whether the LEFT JOIN or the EXISTS would be better.  We need to see both the source of the `id` list and the use of your `COUNTs`.  Note:  In either case, the 2nd of the 3 queries is effectively combined, being very likely to be faster.

Some 3rd party packages lean toward breaking SQL tasks into little steps like this (get ids, check them, use them).  That makes the package much simpler, but it is inefficient for datasets that are "big".

Answer (score 0):

if you have ids as a table then you can use where exists (select 1  from ids where ids.key = NEWS.Key)